facing some issue while using npm audit command in node codebase
When installing a package for my existing codebase, I encountered the following message:
“9 vulnerabilities (3 moderate, 4 high, 2 critical)”
I tried to follow the instructions provided in the terminal to fix these issues. Initially, there were over 22 vulnerabilities, but I managed to resolve many of them. However, I am still left with 9 unresolved vulnerabilities.
I followed all the recommended steps, including updating to the latest versions of all dependencies and running npm audit fix and npm audit fix --force, but the same issues keep recurring.
If anyone has suggestions on how to resolve these remaining vulnerabilities or can guide me through fixing them, your help would be greatly appreciated.
enter image description here
enter image description here
